# How can I check a group of radio buttons value for an if statement in sharepoint?

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, radio-button

I am creating a custom **sharepoint** list and have written some jQuery logic for **hiding/showing/clearing** data entry fields,dropdowns and dates. I need to change the dropdown menus to radio buttons for **yes/no** and I cannot figure out how to change my if statements in the jQuery logic, i wrote to target the radio buttons and check their values.

Does anyone know hot i can target the radio button groups with jquery and get the value of which is checked?

I have tried to target them with

`if($("input[title='Did the Rep call a TM prior to start of shift or leaving for the day?']:checked").val() == "No")` - it didnt work.

````
$("input[title='Did the Rep call a TM prior to start of shift or leaving for the day?']:checked").change(function() {


if ($("input[title='Did the Rep call a TM prior to start of shift or leaving for the day?']:checked").val() == "No"){
    // *******************************Show accountability created? question***********************************
    $('nobr:contains("Accountability discussion created?")').closest('tr').show();

    // *******************************Reset values from previous "Yes" selection*****************************
    $("select[title='Did the Rep report there was an issue with MyWorkLife?']").val("Select Yes or No");
    $("select[title='Did the rep send screenshots?']").val("Select Yes or No");

    // *******************************Hide questions from previous "Yes" selection***************************
    $('nobr:contains("Did the Rep report there was an issue with MyWorkLife?")').closest('tr').hide();
    $('nobr:contains("Did the rep send screenshots?")').closest('tr').hide();


   }
}```

I expect these different rows in the table to either be shown or hidden when the if statement is met - this is only partial code there is "else if" and "else" statements after but didn't think necessary to paste it all.
````

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already in the change function use and targeting the same Check box with the if state use $(this).
Also use single quotes and triple equals.

````
$("input[title='Did the Rep call a TM prior to start of shift or leaving for the day?']:checked").change(function() {

if ($(this).val() === 'No'){
    // *******************************Show accountability created? question***********************************
    $('nobr:contains("Accountability discussion created?")').closest('tr').show();

    // *******************************Reset values from previous "Yes" selection*****************************
    $("select[title='Did the Rep report there was an issue with MyWorkLife?']").val("Select Yes or No");
    $("select[title='Did the rep send screenshots?']").val("Select Yes or No");

    // *******************************Hide questions from previous "Yes" selection***************************
    $('nobr:contains("Did the Rep report there was an issue with MyWorkLife?")').closest('tr').hide();
    $('nobr:contains("Did the rep send screenshots?")').closest('tr').hide();


   }
}```
````